# Calling a javascript function, value returns as undefined in the console

Tags: php, javascript

So I have a city dropdown which is populated by an onchange, I am trying to get it so that it doesn't require the onchange every time the page reloads, since it is a form.

this is the states dropdown, which works.

```
<p id=stateDiv><label>State</label></p><p><select name='States' id='States'  onchange='getCity(this.value)'>
            " . $states . "
        </select></p>";
```

this is the city drop down function call which does not work. I am new to javascript, so I am not sure about how to format a call with php.

```
if($state==""){   
echo '<p id="citydiv"></p>';
}else{
    echo '<p id="citydiv"><script type="text/javascript">getCity('.$state.');</script></p>';
}
```

getCity function

```
function getCity(stateId)
{
  var strURL="findcity.php?state="+stateId;
  var req = getXMLHTTP();
 if (req)
 {
  req.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (req.readyState == 4) // only if "OK"
    {
      if (req.status == 200)
      {
        document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
       } else {
         alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
       }
    }
   }
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript ?

Comment: Where's your js and what are you on about? How do you populate your drop down? Why do you need the on change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get problems like this, ALWAYS look at the HTML source. In this case you might see:

```
getCity(GA);
```

Clearly this is wrong, that should be `"GA"`.

Whenever you dump a PHP variable into JavaScript, always use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode).

Comment: echo '<p id="citydiv"><script type="text/javascript">getCity('.  json_encode($state).');</script></p>';  This did it, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Along with what Kolink said, what does your javascript function "getCity" look like?  If it is just returning a value, this will not work.  You will either need to grab the element (`document.getElementById('cityDiv')`) and set the innerHTML to the return value OR use document.write instead of returning a value.

Comment: I just included it, I have it set this way.